# Cannot pass data to a label with delegation

Tags: swift4

My console prints: "ModelToControllerDelegate.Model".

import Foundation

class Model {
    let firstName: String
    let lastName: String

```
init(firstName: String, lastName: String) {
    self.firstName = firstName
    self.lastName = lastName
}
```

}

import Foundation

protocol DataModelDelegate: class {
    func didRecievedDataUpdate(data: Model)
}

class ModelController {

```
weak var delegate: DataModelDelegate?

func requestData() {
    let data = Model(firstName: "Jack", lastName: "Johnson")
    delegate?.didRecievedDataUpdate(data: data)

}
```

}

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
let modelController = ModelController()

@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    modelController.delegate = self
    modelController.requestData()
}
```

}

extension ViewController: DataModelDelegate {
    func didRecievedDataUpdate(data: Model) {
        print(data)
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

Add In

```
    extension ViewController: DataModelDelegate { 
     func didRecievedDataUpdate(data: Model) { 
     print(data) // data is object of class Model so output is"ModelToControllerDelegate.Model"
     print(data.firstName) // firstName is String so Output is Jack
     print(data.lastName)  // lastName is String so Output is Johnson
     } 
    }
```